# ¿Cómo puedo crear una columna con restas de filas en mysql?

Tags: mysql

Tengo una tabla donde se ingresa el km cada lunes de cada vehículo, quisiera saber cómo realizar la consulta para que **mysql** me entregue los km recorridos de cada vehículo, es decir restar el ultimo ingreso de km con el penúltimo.

tengo la tabla vehiculos con su **primary key** `patente`, y cree esta tabla para el calculo de km

```
CREATE TABLE Km (
  Id_Km INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
  Patente VARCHAR(10),
  Fecha date,
  Km INT,
PRIMARY KEY (Id_Km),
FOREIGN KEY (Patente) REFERENCES Vehiculos (Patente)
);
```

Esta es la tabla en donde se ingresa por patente el km con fecha

id  patente  fecha     km
1   PZTP85  2022-09-05  0
2   PZTP85  2022-09-12  0
3   PZTP85  2022-09-20  20807
4   PZTP85  2022-09-26  21228
5   PZTP85  2022-10-17  22440
6   PZTP85  2022-10-24  22959
7   PZTK29  2022-09-05  0
8   PZTK29  2022-09-12  0
9   PZTK29  2022-09-20  0
10  PZTK29  2022-09-26  14223
11  PZTK29  2022-10-17  15089
12  PZTK29  2022-10-24  0

he podido calcular el recorrido por patente con esta consulta

```
SELECT (SELECT Km FROM Km WHERE Patente='PZTK25' AND Fecha='2022-09-12')-
(SELECT Km FROM Km WHERE Patente='PZTK25' AND Fecha='2022-09-05') AS Recorrido
```

que me entrega

recorrido
471

quisiera saber como puedo obtener lo siguiente

patente  recorrido
PZTP85      519
PZTK29      866
PZTK25      471

donde el recorrido es el ultimo km ingresado menos el anterior
ojala alguien me pueda ayudar

Comment: Podrías poner un ejemplo de que hace tu consulta y qué es lo que deseas lograr?

Comment: ¿Similar a lo que se pidió en [esta pregunta](/q/452954)?

Comment: similar, pero esa respuesta entrega todas las restas, yo solo deseo la ultima por patente

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si tu versión de MySQL soporta Common Table Expressions:

```
WITH 
    t AS (SELECT  Patente, Fecha, Km, Km - LAG(km) over(PARTITION BY Patente ORDER BY Fecha) AS dif
    FROM Km
    WHERE Km <> 0)
SELECT Patente, Fecha, dif FROM t AS t0 
WHERE Fecha >= ALL(select Fecha FROM t WHERE patente = t0.Patente)
```

devuelve la última fecha cargada y la diferencia en KM.
Notar que filtro `WHERE Km <> 0` porque en tu ejemplo hay un registro con fecha posterior que tiene 0 km registrados, y la diferencia daría negativa

Comment: muchas gracias, me ha servido mucho y he podido aprender mas